# Count the number of vowelgroups in a string

Tags: python, beginner, strings

I've written a function that can count the vowel groups in a string.

```
def count_vowelgroups(woord):
    if woord[0].lower() in 'aeiouy':
        output = 1
    else:
        output = 0

    for i in range(1, len(woord)):
        if woord[i].lower() in 'aeiouy' and woord[i-1].lower() not in 'aeiouy':
            output += 1
    return output
```

It works fine, but not really pythonic! Who can help?

For example:

```
print(count_vowelgroups('Hello everyone!'))
6
print(count_vowelgroups('Alright'))
2
print(count_vowelgroups('Whaaaaaat!?'))
1
print(count_vowelgroups('Je pense donc je suis.'))
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`itertools` recipe `pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) you can directly use `sum` to calculate the number of vowel groups by iterating over pairs of values.

In addition I would make the vowels a global constant and a `set`, because building the string every time is going to cost some time. Also, `set`s have very fast membership testing.

With these changes you would get:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

VOWELS = set("aeiouy")

def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."""
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def count_vowelgroups(words):
    words = words.lower()
    return sum(c_1 not in VOWELS and c in VOWELS for c_1, c in pairwise(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you handle the 1st word outside of the for loop? Is there any specific reason for doing so?

If you simply initialize

```
output = 0
```

and run through the range *[0 - (len(word) - 1)[* like

```
for i in range(len(word) - 1):
```

and change the condition to

```
if i >= 0 and woord[i].lower() in 'aeiouy' and woord[i+1].lower() not in 'aeiouy':
```

you should receive the same result with shorter code.

---

Also the parameter name `word` sounds odd for me. One could think a single word is expected as parameter, but you obviously pass more than a single word there.

I'd recommend to rename that to `words`, `sentence` or `text` for clarity.